# Getting Value from div with class having another blank tag Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the value '5' of from the following :

```
<div class="DrugPriceBox__price___dj2lv">₹<!-- -->5</div>
```

and the python-beautifulsoup code i used returns Nothing:

```
drugprice=soup.find('div', class_="DrugPriceBox__price___dj2lv")

print(drugprice)
```

The webpage url is: https://www.1mg.com/drugs/acticort-5mg-tablet-321932

Thank you in advance!

Additional information:

The WORKING CODE after solving the problem:

```html
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #turl='https://www.1mg.com/drugs/acticort-5mg-tablet-321932'
    turl='https://www.1mg.com/drugs/zerodol-sp-tablet-67307'
    print (turl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(turl,headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
    #type 'div' pricing format
    div = soup.find('div', class_='DrugPriceBox__price___dj2lv')
    if div:
        print(div.text)
    else:
        #type 'span' pricing format
        #span =soup.find('span', class_="PriceBoxPlanOption__offer-price___3v9x8 PriceBoxPlanOption__offer-price-cp___2QPU_")
        span =soup.find('span', class_="PriceBoxPlanOption__margin-right-4___2aqFt PriceBoxPlanOption__stike___pDQVN")      
        if span:
            print(span.text)
        else:
            print('Nada')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are getting an error. I cannot see the original site as it is blocked for some reason, but running an express server with exactly the div that you entered, and using the below worked fine for me with the below.

```
import string

import bs4
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:3000/')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    div = soup.find('div', class_='DrugPriceBox__price___dj2lv')
    acceptable_chars = set(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '.')
    drugprice = ''.join(char for char in div.text if char in acceptable_chars)
    print(drugprice)
```

Comment: I tried based on your tip, but didn't work.  In my code, if i try to  print(drugprice.text) it throws and error :    print(drugprice.txt)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'txt' ( wil add the html source extract to my question )

Comment: Are you sure that you are successfully getting a 200 response from the webpage, with all of the data in it?  It seems that the div isn't being found, which suggests it is not present in the data.

Comment: yes, i am able to get other values from same webpage, only this particular 'drugprice' is the issue!

Comment: took some cues from you  ,  I rewrote the code  and it started working. The issue was the webpage inconsistencies.